# Service call onServiceConnected even before bind other Service completely

Tags: android, aidl, android-intentservice

I have a following case:

I am developing service that is going to bind manufacturer service via AIDL Interface, in it's onCreate() method.

The problem is when activity bind my service, it receive onServiceConnected, before the manufacturer service is been connected and if some of my service methods been called from activity, they can not be proceed because second service is not been bound completely.

I can not bind manufacturer service directly from activity, because Our system require other apps to call this functionality, they are going to bind my service via other AIDL Interface.

I am looking for way to slow down calling of onServiceConnected method while second service is been bound completely.

Comment: return from `onBind()`  a custom "proxy" `Binder` object and override its `onTransact` method "throwing" `IllegalStateException` if not ready yet

Comment: errr, you can even override `onTransact` in your `Stub` so no need for extra "proxy" `Binder`

Comment: that's exactly what I did, looking good, thank you so much! :)

Comment: do you know how to "throw" `IllegalStateException` inside `onTransact`?

Comment: I think so, inside my Stub I'm doing following:

@Override
        public boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply, int flags) throws RemoteException, IllegalArgumentException {
            if (mICloudService == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Method not completely bound");

            return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
        }

Comment: actually there is `Parcel#writeException` - you need to call it on `Parcel reply` i believe but not 100% sure...

Comment: it throws this exception when I'm trying to call from activity some of aidl methods, before second service been completely bound, its not bad workaround, I've been looking how to delay onServiceConnected but it may be impossible